# ESC (in VI) on FreeBSD as Guest in VirtualBox on macOSX does not work. Neither over VB own screen, nor via Terminal > SSH

Tags: freebsd, vi, macos

I just installed FreeBSD-12-Current as guest of VirtualBox6 on my MacBook Pro 15° 2018 with TouchBar under macOS Mojave 10.14.6 an then installed "SUDO" on the virtual machine. When I try to configure sudo via VISUDO I cannot leave insert-mode with ESC. Als I get is " ^[ " for every click on ESC. This is always the same, either if I do this via the emulated screen of VB direct or via macOS-Terminal > ssh.

If I start vim on my host (macOS) in terminal, everything works just as expected.

Shell in FreeBSD is sh.
and keyboard is set to German.

What could be the problem / resolution?

Kind regards.